# SQL: select specific triads of users

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a table of users:

```
User(id INT, username VARCHAR(30))
```

and directed relations between them:

```
Following(follower_id INT, followee_id INT)
```

I need a SELECT for all unique triads of users such as:

```
A   follows   B
B   follows   A
A   follows   C
C not follows A
B not follows C
C   follows   B
```

I am working with SQLite database and using Python. With a SELECT for above example at hand I will probably be quick to do all the rest of triads I am after. These are essentially all possible combinations of directed connections within a triad of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ab.follower_id AS a_id,
       ab.followee_id AS b_id,
       ac.followee_id AS c_id
FROM following AS ab
JOIN following AS ba ON ab.followee_id = ba.follower_id
                    AND ab.follower_id = ba.followee_id
JOIN following AS ac ON ab.follower_id = ac.follower_id
JOIN following AS cb ON ac.followee_id = cb.follower_id
                    AND ab.followee_id = cb.followee_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN following AS ca ON ac.followee_id = ca.follower_id
                               AND ac.follower_id = ca.followee_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN following AS bc ON cb.followee_id = bc.follower_id
                               AND cb.follower_id = bc.followee_id
WHERE ab.follower_id < ab.followee_id
  AND ab.followee_id < ac.followee_id
  AND ca.follower_id IS NULL
  AND bc.follower_id IS NULL
```

At 3 million records this executes in 30 seconds compared to 45k seconds of version with `EXIST`s proposed by Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated, but you can do it:

```
with pairs as (
      select f1.followee_id, f1.follower_id
      from following f1 join
           following f2
           on f1.follower_id = f2.followee_id and
              f1.followee_id = f2.follower_id
     )
select p1.followee as A, p1.follower as B, p3.followee as C
from pairs p1 join
     pairs p2
     on p1.followee_id = p2.followee_id join
     pairs p3
     on p3.followee_id = p1.follower_id and
        p3.follower_id = p2.follower_id;
```

The idea is that `pairs` get pairs of users that follow each other.  Then look for other pairs that add a third person.

An alternative approach is to generate all combinations and then choose the ones that match:

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id
from users a join
     users b
     on a.id < b.id join
     users c
     on b.id < c.id
where exists (select 1 from following f where f.follower_id = a.id and f.followee_id = b.id) and
      exists (select 1 from following f where f.follower_id = b.id and f.followee_id = a.id) and
      exists (select 1 from following f where f.follower_id = a.id and f.followee_id = c.id) and
      exists (select 1 from following f where f.follower_id = c.id and f.followee_id = a.id) and
      exists (select 1 from following f where f.follower_id = b.id and f.followee_id = c.id) and
      exists (select 1 from following f where f.follower_id = c.id and f.followee_id = b.id);
```

This version might actually have better performance, if you have reasonable indexes set up on your tables.

EDIT:

For performance, the `following` table should have indexes on `follower_id, followee_id` -- this is a composite index with two columns.

Comment: With almost 3 million rows in the Following table this SELECT takes forever. I created indices for all rows used here but it brings no increase in performance.

Comment: Also the not exists clauses I needed to add didn't do performance any good. Any other ideas?

Comment: @kjrz . . . I don't see any `not exists` clause.  If you have a performance question about another query, you might consider asking *another* question.

Comment: Without extra `NOT EXISTS` clauses the `SELECT` does not return the triad I am after. Such triad must contain only the connections listed in the original question.

Comment: I added _not follows_ relations in my original question to stress the exact structure of triads I am after.

Comment: @kjrz . . . Replacing `EXISTS` with `NOT EXISTS` in the second query should not have a large impact on performance, assuming you have the right indexes.